# Proxy to flask server

Tags: python, node.js, flask, proxy

I created a flask server and wanted to create a proxy so that I can redirect any requests from my Node.js app to the flask server.

The flask is running correctly:
`curl http://localhost:5000 Hello World!`
But the proxy from my app.js gives me an ECONNREFUSED.
I believe it should be an issue with my app.js, here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
var axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

//not for you =)
const options = {
    key:
    cert: 
    ca: 
}



//python server connection @Localhost:5000
proxy = {
    target: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    changeOrigin: false,
    secure:false,
    headers:{'Connection':'keep-alive'},
    pathRewrite: {'^/pharma': ''}
};
  
app.use('/pharma', createProxyMiddleware(proxy));
  

var server = https.createServer(options,app);

server.listen(443, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at https://%s:%s", host, port)
 })

const httpApp = express();
httpApp.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../home/karion/Webpage/Client/redirectHTTPs.html'));
});

const httpServer = http.createServer(httpApp);
httpServer.listen(80, () => console.log(`HTTP server listening: http://localhost`));
```

I tried different properties for proxy (the input variable of app.use).